# socket.io 1.0 client library for android

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io

I want socket.io client library for android.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

It seems to work well. But document say it doesn't support socket.io server 1.x.

I have socket.io server 1.0 and client written by swift and javascript. There were already have run as a products. So, I can not replace socket.io server to 0.9.x.

I need the following function for android socket.io library.

(1) Connect the socket.io 1.0 server with https.

(2) Join a particular room and chat.

Does anyone know the solution for this purpose? Please let me know.